# Difference between "requisite" and "prerequisite"

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between requisite and prerequisite?

> A is a requisite for B

> A is a prerequisite for B

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have statistics, but I believe "prerequisite" is more common as a noun ("X is a prerequisite for Y") while "requisite" is more common as an adjective ("Please bring the requisite items for X"). Having said that, it's not clear-cut, and you can use either as noun or adjective.

Comment: In my location it sounds funny to say "A is a requisite for B." It would be more common to say "A is requisite for B," but even that would be unusual. Something like "We'll do B once we have the requisite A's" would be more common. But I agree with @StuartF, it's much, much more common to hear "prerequisite."

Comment: Is it ok to say "A is a prerequisite for B" in your location?

Answer (score 2):

[Requisite:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/requisite) Something needed for a particular purpose.

[Prerequisite:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prerequisite) Something that must happen or exist before something else happens or exists.

There is substantial overlap in the meanings. Prerequisite emphasizes the aspect of the required thing to exist or happen before the dependent thing. Requisite leaves the time ordering as implicit. Otherwise, they are the same.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that a "requisite" is by necessity something "pre", so "prerequisite" is sort of redundant?

Comment: @bobpeck Often but not always. One could say "A nice walk is a requisite for me after drinking coffee", in the sense that if the walk is not possible, one would skip drinking the coffee. But it sounds strange to say "A nice walk is a prerequisite for me after drinking coffee". Sorry for the silly example, I hope you get the gist of it. Not sure I'm commanding the use of "requisite" properly in this example.